# Copy from one ListObject to another VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

More a question of writing nice VBA code here, since it technically works. I have a simple task - I need to copy data from one ListObject (2 columns from  4-column table) and add it to the end of another 2-column table (and have the Excel table autoexpand).

I created Range **Trans_log**, for addressing those 2 columns I need to copy. I'm targeting the newly created ListRow through **newrow**, in order not to accidentially paste data somewhere in the middle of the table.

However is there a neater way to do this, instead of using *With*, *.Activate* and *ActiveCell* ?

```
Sub Copy()

Dim newrow As ListRow
Set newrow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Log").ListRows.Add

ActiveSheet.Range("Trans_log").Copy

With newrow

.Range(1).Activate
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this - directly assign the values instead of copy/paste

```
Sub Copy()

    Dim newrow As ListRow
    With ActiveSheet
        Set newrow = .ListObjects("Log").ListRows.Add()
        newrow.Range.Value = .Range("Trans_log").Value 
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: for copying multiple rows

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim newrow As ListRow
    Dim lst As ListObject, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = Sheets(1)
    Set lst = sht.ListObjects("Log")

    'loop over rows in named range
    For Each rw In sht.Range("Trans_log").Rows
        'only copy rows with data
        If Application.CountA(rw) > 0 Then
            Set newrow = lst.ListRows.Add()
            newrow.Range.Value = rw.Value
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Unfortuantely that reports an error "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: on which line ?

Comment: Tested - works for me provided "Trans_log" is the same shape as the new table row.

Comment: Hi again! Got past the initial error - I was not launching from the same sheet, so adjusting "With ActiveSheet" into "With Sheets(2)" fixed it.

Still, a problem persist which you probably also hint at. "Trans_log" is a range of 2 columns (as is Table "Log" - so the data itself fits), however I'm trying to add multiple rows at the same time and was expecting the table to expand as needed. The code does not report any errors anymore, however only adds the 1st row from "Trans_log" range into Table "Log".